# How to define $\Lambda^0_0$, 0-horn of a simplicial point

Tags: simplicial-stuff

This is really a trivial question.

The 0-horn of a simplicial point $\Delta^0$ is not defined nor remarked in the books and papers I could find. So one expect if we could make some meaningful definition (like $0!=1$). The usual definition of $\Lambda^n_k$ for $n>1, 0\le k\le n$ simply does not make sense.

It is quite clear that the boundary $\partial\Delta^0$ should be $\emptyset$, the constant simplicial set with value $\emptyset$. However the 0-horn should be strict smaller than $\partial\Delta^0$, which is already the smallest simplicial set.

Comment: I think you answered your question in the last sentence: $\Lambda^0_0 \subseteq \partial \Delta^0 = \emptyset$.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I am not satisfied with the only possibility $Λ^0_0=∂Δ^0$. I think there should be better solution (like enlarge the category of simplicial sets).

Comment: If you work with presheaves over the augmented simplex category, then it's natural to define $\partial\Delta^0=\Delta^{-1}$ and $\Lambda^0_0$ to actually be the empty presheaf.  I don't know if this is useful.

Comment: I think the 0-horn is best left undefined or non-existent (even in the augmented simplex category). After all, one of the most important properties of a horn is that it is a weak equivalence. That cannot be arranged for in the case of a 0-horn.

Comment: @EricWofsey This will make the identity $(Λ^{m}_{k}\starΔ^{n}) \cup (Δ^{m}\star \partial Δ^{n})=Λ^{m+1+n}_{k}$ hold for $m=k=0$.

Comment: The join is really an operation on augmented simplicial sets so the comment by Eric is of importance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As already mentioned, we have to specify whether we're talking about *simplicial sets* or about *augmented simplicial sets*; I will be talking about simplicial sets.)

I agree with Ricardo Andrade: the simplex $\Delta^0$ has no horns.

The horns of a simplex $\Delta^n$ correspond to the (maximal) proper faces of $\Delta^n$, and those can already be defined within the simplex category $\Delta$. As there is no proper subobject of $\Delta^0$ in the category $\Delta$, the simplex $\Delta^0$ has no horns.

Comment: then why we do not define it to be $\emptyset$?

Comment: Of course you may define anything you want. But if you want the horns of a simplex $\Delta^n$ to bijectively correspond to the maximal proper subobjects of $\Delta^n$ in the simplex category $\Delta$, then the simplex $\Delta^0$ has no horns.

Comment: (Remember that $\emptyset$ is not contained in the simplex category $\Delta$.)